# Why is the setting about font.family in matplotlibrc not reflected?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I use macOS and python3.7. 
I'm having trouble setting up fonts in Matplotlib.
I'm trying to set the font to Times New Roman in Matplotlib.

In matplotlibrc file (which is located in `/Users/my_name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2019.10/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data`), I changed 
`#font.family:  sans-serif` into `font.family:  serif` 
and 
`#font.serif:      DejaVu Serif, ..., Times New Roman, ...` into `font.serif:      Times New Roman, ...`

After setting the matplotlibrc file as described above, I invoked the interactive shell by typing `python` in the terminal.

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> mpl.matplotlib_fname()
'/Users/my_name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2019.10/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc'
>>> plt.rcParams['font.family']
['serif']
>>> plt.rcParams['font.serif']
['Times New Roman', 'DejaVu Serif', 'Bitstream Vera Serif', 'Computer Modern Roman', 'New Century Schoolbook', 'Century Schoolbook L', 'Utopia', 'ITC Bookman', 'Bookman', 'Nimbus Roman No9 L', 'Times', 'Palatino', 'Charter', 'serif']
```

As you can see above, the settings have been successfully applied so far.
But, when I created main.py shown below

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(mpl.matplotlib_fname())
print(plt.rcParams["font.family"])
print(plt.rcParams['font.serif'])
```

and ran it with `python main.py` in the terminal. The output was

```
/Users/my_name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2019.10/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
['sans-serif']
['Times New Roman', ..., 'serif']
```

and it turns out that the font.family setting is not reflected. 
When I actually created the graph, the Times New Roman font was not applied. In addition, I added 
`print(plt.rcParams["font.sans-serif"])` 
to the main.py and the output was 
`['Arial', 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'sans-serif']`
, which is different from the settings 
`#font.sans-serif: DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, Computer Modern Sans Serif, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Geneva, Lucid, Arial, Helvetica, Avant Garde, sans-serif`
in the matplotlibrc.

In the interactive shell, `plt.rcParams["font.sans-serif"]` correctly output `#font.sans-serif: DejaVu Sans, ...` as described in the matplotlibrc.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me why this is happening when the settings were reflected in the interactive shell. I'm not very confident in my English, so please let me know if there is anything that is difficult to understand.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to remove the comment symbol `#` from the beginning of the lines in `matplotlibrc` that you want to have an effect

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I removed the # as you suggested, and in addition, removed the cache file, but it didn't change the result. "print(plt.rcParams["font.family"])" still outputs "["sans-serif]" and Times New Roman is not used in the graph.

Comment: Do you have an environment activated? Why not setting the parameters in python? [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rc.html) is a short description in the matplotlib-docs

Comment: I don't believe it is the cause of this problem whether an environment is activated since I don't use virtual environments.
I had already confirmed that  ```plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'``` would work correctly, so writing that command every time actually solves the font problem. But it's a bit of a pain to do so, and so I'm looking for a solution to this problem...
Thank you very much.